# Find first non repeating character without using hashmap

Tags: java

I wanted to find first non repeating character in a string. I wrote the following function in which I am stuck at one point. Google tells me the hashmap method for this but I'll be grateful if someone could help me with my code.

```
public static Character firstNonRepeatedChar(String line) {

        Character c = null;
        int strLength = line.length();

        for (int i =0; i<strLength-1; i++){

            int flag = 0;
            for(int j = i+1; j<strLength-i; j++){

                if(line.charAt(i) == line.charAt(j)){
                    flag++;
                    break;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }

            if (flag==0){
                c = line.charAt(i);
                break;
            }


        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Problem : How can I put a check that the repeating character that is already checked once is not checked again.
Ex: If my string is "hhello" then the code first compares the h at index 0 with all the other characters. Since its repeating the next iteration of outer for loop starts in which i now points to index 1 of the string i.e the repeating h and compares it with the rest of elements. Since it does not get a repeating instance it returns 'h' as non repeating character which is wrong.

How can I fix this? Is there any way?
Pls help

EDIT: Repeating character need not be the immediate next character. 
Ex: In string "helloWorld" characters 'l' and 'o' are repeating.
    In string "hehelo" characters 'h' and 'e' are repeating and first non     repeating character will be 'l'

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the repeating nature? Is is a immediate following character sequence like `abccdefg` or is it like `abcdefdg`?

Comment: @Hannes It need not be the immediate following character sequence. Please see the edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***For all case of repetition

```
Character c = null;
    int strLength = line.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) {

        int flag = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < strLength; j++) {
            if (line.charAt(i) == line.charAt(j) && i != j) {
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0) {
            c = line.charAt(i);
            break;
        }

    }
    return c;
```

This is so simple to check, Your logic is complex. try this for immediate repeated character.

```
Character c = null;
        int strLength = line.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < strLength - 1;) {

            int flag = 0;
            int present_char_position = 0;

            if (line.charAt(i) == line.charAt(i + 1)) {
                flag++;
                present_char_position = i;
                i += 2;//jumping from those two character if matched
                continue;
            } else {
                present_char_position = i;
                i++;//if not matched go to next character
            }

            if (flag == 0) {
                c = line.charAt(present_char_position);
                break;
            }

        }
        return c;
```

Comment: your solution works well for the case when the repeating character means the immediate next character in the sequence, but in my case it is not necessary so we have to check each character against all other characters. Please see the EDIT. 
Thanks

Comment: Answer (***) is edited for all case of repetition. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: If you got your answer please accept the answer. @Arushigupta

Comment: welcome, then kindly press the solved button of my answer, and make this question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint* 1: A repeating character<sup>1</sup> is one that is the same as the previous character in the String.  A non-repeating character is .........

Implement that!

*Hint 2*: You *don't* need a nested loop.

---

**UPDATE**

I see.  So you are using "non-repeating character" to mean something different to what most people would mean.  What you are *actually* looking for is the first character that appears only once in the entire string.

Anyway ... at least I now understand why you are using a nested loop now, and I understand the bug.

*Hint 3*: Even when a character appears multiple time in a string, it will still appear ZERO times after its last occurrence.

That is what your inner loop tests for.  So what you are finding is the first character in the string that isn't duplicated in the remainder of the string.

The fix is simple ... once you *understand* what you are doing wrong.

---

Once you have fixed that are some other tidy ups:

- The `else continue` is redundant.
- The `c` variable is unnecessary ... if you change:

  ```
      if (flag==0){
          c = line.charAt(i);
          break;
      }
  ```

  to

  ```
      if (flag==0){
          return line.charAt(i);
      }
  ```

  and

  ```
      return c;
  ```

  to

  ```
      return null;
  ```

---

<sup>1 - This is what a native English speaker understands by "find the first non-repeating character". It is possible that you mean something else.  If so, please update the question to clarify.  Please describe as clearly as you can what you mean.  Please give examples.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to flag doublets would be to replace the characters with a none printable one. You can then skip these positions. But this will add another O(n) to your loop replacing the characters. The worst case would result in O(n^3). Optimizing you could write an inner loop replacing only the characters ahead of your current position. This would result in a O(n^2) again, because currently you have O(n^2) (n*n/2).

**UPDATE**
Added code and fixed a bug, where the non repeating character is at last position of the `String`. 
Instead of processing the `String`, now processing the `char[]`.

```
private static final char FLAG = '\u0000';

public static Character firstNonRepeatedChar(String line)
{
    final char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
    Character c = null;

    final int strLength = chars.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++)
    {
        if (chars[i] == FLAG)
        {
            continue;
        }

        int flag = 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < strLength; j++)
        {
            if (chars[i] == chars[j])
            {
                flag++;
                chars[j] = FLAG;
            }
        }

        if (flag == 0)
        {
            c = chars[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: I could not understand : line = line.substring(0, j) + FLAG + line.substring(j+1)
If string is "hehelo" then the program will enter into the if block at j=2.
According to me, line.substring(0,j) = heh + null + elo
But when I debug this in Eclipse I see the value of line as : 'he elo'
Please explain where I am going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: I noticed the spacy display of `\u0000` too. In your case, the following `h` is flaged, and not `e`.

Comment: As an improvement, use a char array.

Answer (score 0):

Below method will return you what you are looking.

```
public static char getFirstNonRepeatedChar(String input) {        
    char c = 0;
    for (int i =0; i<input.length(); i++){
        int flag = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j<input.length(); j++){
            if(input.charAt(i) == input.charAt(j)){
                flag++;
            }
            if(flag>1)
                break;
        }
        if (flag == 1){
            c = input.charAt(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is for PHP

```
<?php

$string = "ABBGAACCE";

$stringArray = str_split($string); // string converted to array
$temp_array = [];
$non_repeating_array = get_first_non_repeating($stringArray, $temp_array);

echo reset($non_repeating_array); // display first non repeating character from string

function get_first_non_repeating($stringArray, $temp_array)
{
    $repeating = []; // store all repeating characters
    foreach($stringArray as $key => $char)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($char, $temp_array)) // check if character was already saved meaning it is repeating
        {
            array_push($repeating, $char); // push all repeating character in a variable
            $stringArray = array_diff($stringArray, $repeating); // subtract repeating characters from the string array
        }else{
            $temp_array[$char] = 1;
        }
    }
    return $stringArray; // returns the non repeating characters
}
```